# Negative Decimals in EditText

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

i am coding a small calculator.
I have 3 edittext fields which are written like this:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/zField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="c"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

When i try to input a negativ decimal, the "-" just won't appear so i can't input any negativ numbers.
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

specify numberSigned input type as below

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```